# python: multiple print lines to be overwritten

Tags: python, string, printing, overwrite

Sorry for the noob question, I checked out other similar questions on the website but couldn't find one that solves my problem.

I'm very new to python so forgive me.
I'm trying to make a bot which shows results of my trading account.

First step I would like to be able to see results in the terminal.
Second step will be "writing those results on a webpage"

what i would like to achieve is that every single line of print get updated with new values on the same original lines.

the portion code of the function is this:

```
def eth_results():
    eth = s.get_wallet_balance()['result']['ETH']
    eth_starting_balance = 0.05015276
    eth_balance = eth['wallet_balance']
    eth_equity = eth['equity']
    eth_daily_pnl = format(eth['realised_pnl'],'.8f')
    eth_percentage_pnl = eth_starting_balance * (eth_starting_balance / (eth_balance - eth_starting_balance))
    print('\n--------------------------------------\n')
    print(f'Coin: ETHEREUM')
    print(f'Balance: {eth_balance}')
    print(f'Starting Balance: {eth_starting_balance}')
    print(f'Total Profit: {eth_percentage_pnl}')
    print(f'Total Equity: {eth_equity}')
    print('\n--------------------------------------\n')
```

then I'm telling it to repeat each 5 seconds

```
while True:
  eth_results()
  time.sleep(5)
```

right now the output is like this **but i would like to have the results printed in the same lines, updating just the variables**:

```
--------------------------------------

Coin: ETHEREUM
Balance: 0.0513822
Starting Balance: 0.05015276
Total Profit: 2.0458902716827083
Total Equity: 0.05133733

--------------------------------------


--------------------------------------

Coin: ETHEREUM
Balance: 0.0513822
Starting Balance: 0.05015276
Total Profit: 2.0458902716827083
Total Equity: 0.05133754

--------------------------------------


--------------------------------------

Coin: ETHEREUM
Balance: 0.0513822
Starting Balance: 0.05015276
Total Profit: 2.0458902716827083
Total Equity: 0.05133706

--------------------------------------
```

but I can't achieve it.
If i use the **\r** only the last line will be replaced. Basically I would like to replace ALL the lines.
I'm pretty sure there are multiple ways to achieve this, and multiple ways to "clean the code" but right now I'm just willing to find ANY "working solution" rather than finding "the only best way" to do it. Of course I'm willing to code in a better way when I'll gain more experience.

**BONUS**: after that I would also like to basically print (and ovewrite) the same thing on a text/html/whatever kind of file. But this is not the priority now.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can print a bunch of new lines to clear the console.

```
clear = "\n" * 100
print(clear)
```

You cannot overwrite an already printed line in the console since it is an output.

Comment: but if I use the \r I can overwrite the last line. 
I can't believe there is no way to overwrite more than 1 line. But I can be totally wrong!

Comment: \r is a carriage return, you essentially moved the cursor back to the beginning of the line, that is why you are able to overwrite the last line.
You can think of it like a typewriter, you can move down to the next line (\n) and then you need to move the cursor back to the beginning (\r)

you can't go to another line though.

Answer (score 1):

I created a method I regularly use to clean `x` lines before calling the code. It sets the print cursor `x` lines up with `"\x1b[{0}A"` and then executes the `'\033[J'` which cleans the terminal from the line the cursor is located to the end of the screen.

To know more about ANSI codes see [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

```
def clean_lines_up(number_of_lines):
    cursor = '\x1b[{0}A'.format(number_of_lines)
    print(cursor, end="")
    clean_to_end = '\033[J'
    print(clean_to_end, end="")
```

In your case, if i'm not missing any `'\n'`, you could do that by calling:

```
clean_lines_up(10)
```

Then you could print another result and it would go in the place the other one was.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following

```
import os
print('text')
os.system("clear")
```